# Specify relations between divs

Tags: html, href, rel

I have a collection of fairly large page elements which, when clicked, slide out and slide in new elements. It would be nice to use `<a>` tags to link the elements together, but unfortunately the content inside each element can't be expressed solely in `<span>`s and other content-level elements, so I have to use a `<div>` as the clickable element.

What is the best way to specify the relations between the elements using a `<div>` or similar?

I could do something like:

```
<div id="attribute-1" rel="{href: '#subattribute-1'}">Details about subattribute 1</div>
```

and parse the `rel` element into Javascript. But using the `rel` element like that feels hacky; is there a better solution that I'm missing?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "What is the best way to specify the relations between the elements using a <div> or similar?"?  What do  you mean by "relations"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `data-*` attributes.  Like `data-target`.  Or you could wrap the `div` in an `a` (valid in HTML5)